# AWS Lambda zip file command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, zip

I was experiencing issue with running lambda function with uploaded `.zip` file of Python script, which always produces `"Unable to import module '...': No module named ..."` (I have made sure my lambda handler matched my Python file name),  and through online research, I have found that the way files are zipped is very strict in this case.

The solution provided following command examples

Wrong command:

```
$ ls 
   lambda_sample
$ zip -r lambda_sample lambda_sample
```

Correct command:

```
$ cd lambda_sample
$ zip -r ../lambda_sample .
```

And indeed, the second command worked for me.

So I wonder why won't the first command work? Also, I'm using macOS, and by right clicking folder and `Compress [folder_name]` would produce a `[folder_name].zip` file not readable by Lambda, hence produce the same error I mentioned in the beginning. Could anyone provide any insight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AWS Lambda expects your handler in the base/root of the zip file, and the `zip` commands you show generate different file layouts.

I'll demonstrate with some examples from my own system.

This is an example of your first command:

```
> ls
package
> zip -r package package
 adding: package/ (stored 0%)
 adding: package/lambda.py (deflated 38%)
 adding: package/process/ (stored 0%)
 adding: package/process/__init__.py (stored 0%)
 adding: package/process/aws.py (deflated 56%)
 # ... etc.
```

If I `unzip package.zip`, the folder structure of the resultant unzipped file looks like this:

```
package/lambda.py
package/process/
package/process/__init__.py
# and so on
```

Now, an example of your second command, where I `cd package` first:

```
> zip -r ../package .
adding: lambda.py (deflated 38%)
adding: process/ (stored 0%)
# ... etc.
```

So the resulting unzipped file if I `unzip package.zip` looks like this:

```
lambda.py
process/
process/__init__.py
# etc.
```

So in the second case, you don't have the parent directory after expanding the ZIP, and AWS Lambda will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do every time:

1. Create a virtual env to install dependencies:

   ```
    python3 -m venv nameOfYourVenvFolder
   ```
2. Go into folder and activate virtual env:

   ```
    cd nameOfYourVenvFolder
    source bin/activate
   ```
3. Install dependency that will be accessible to Lambda:

   ```
    pip3 install mysql-connector -t .
   ```
4. Make dependencies compatible with Lambda (Linux). i.e. delete any appearances of pycache or .dist-info files:

   ```
    rm *.dist-info
    rmdir __pycache__
   ```
5. Compress the file. You can do this in Terminal, but it's easy to just select all files > right click > compress (on Mac; Windows is similar).
6. Upload .zip file to S3 and then to Lambda if .zip file is over 50mb. A .zip file under 50mb can be uploaded to Lambda directly.

Let me know if you need more specific help, and I'll be happy to answer!